# Can't update WP Editor after Ajax

Tags: ajax, wp-editor

I want to update the WP Editor textarea after Ajax, but it does not work.

I have the following in my Ajax success function:

```
$('input#pn').val(response.name);

$('select').val( response.category_name );

$('textarea#pd').val(response.description);

$('textarea#ld').val(response.long_description);
```

`ld` is the id of the `wp_editor` textarea.

The first three work but the fourth one is `wp_editor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$('textarea#ld').val(response.long_description);
```

With:

```
tinyMCE.get('ld').setContent(response.long_description);
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.